# Is it safe to run wordpress sites and rdp combined on one single server?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, wordpress, rdp, remoteapp

In my company I set up an IIS webserver with two wordpress sites and an FTP server on it. On the same server, I got my company's applications running through RemoteApp and with an RDP gateway (clients need to access those applications). Since my applications have sensitive information, I just wanted to make sure that this set up is OK.

Is it safe to run those two wordpress sites on the same server as my RDP services? What are the possible risks? Or should I definitely separate them?

PS: Of course I took every possible measure to secure those websites (firewalls, wordpress addons...).

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is about the most used CMS and therefore also quite possibly the most hacked piece of FOSS so in general, it's not a good idea to mix it in with other sensitive applications. Given you cheap (and performant) basic Wordpress hosting is, it's probably not worth the money savings.

But of course, I have no idea of how secure you made it, and intend to keep it. Also no idea of the potential cost of a breach. Ultimately only you know enough details to answer this question. In general tough, no, it's not a good idea.

To make it work like this, you need to pull out al the stops to build a Fort Knoxx, and that costs a lot of time, effort and potentially money.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's probably not a great idea. However, you can probably do it securely if you're careful.

Under Linux this would mean doing a few things:

- Running separate PHP pools for each site, as different users
- Having a database for each site, with different users so each user / PHP pool can only access their own database
- Being very strict about file ownership

Set up like this, even if Wordpress or your web server is compromised the access they have is very limited. However, doing it well probably requires a reasonably experienced administrator. Under Windows I don't know how you'd do this.